# Boostrap 4 Navbar does not work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I'm new to Bootstrap. I installed Bootstrap 4 and took the Navbar code directly from Bootstrap 4 Navbar example code, but the code does not show the navigation - it only shows the menu icon. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/bootstrap.js">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Bootstrap V4 Beta navbar is different to the Bootstrap V4 Alpha navbar.

Here's an example Bootstrap v4 Beta navbar taken from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This partially solved the issue. I also needed to use Brock Marek's suggestion of adding jQuery CDN to make it work. I'm surprised that going from Bootstrap 4. Alpha to Bootstrap 4 Beta uses different code. Should I worry that when Bootstrap 4 Production comes up, the code can stop working and I'll be needing to use an updated code?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which version of bootstrap you are using. However you are missing Jquery CDN which will definitely break bootstrap.

Get rid of the Bootstrap JS at the start of your html doc and add this at the end. (jquery must be referenced before bootstrap JS.)

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the navbar of an old bootstrap version.
You need to get the template of bootstrap 4.
Follow the link:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/